# The type or namespace name 'ThirdPersonUserControl' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

**I'm creating a Third Person joystick controller
but I can't figure out this error.**

code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ThirdPersonInput : MonoBehaviour
{
public FixedJoystick LeftJoystick;
public FixedButton Button;
public ThirdPersonUserControl Control;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    Control = GetComponent<ThirdPersonUserControl>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    Control.m_Jump = Button.Pressed;
    Control.Hinput = LeftJoystick.inputVector.x;
    Control.Vinput = LeftJoystick.inputVector.y;

}
```

}

Please help...

Comment: If you have ur `ThirdPersonUserControl` script in a different folder you have to import the location. You can click on the error, this should provide you with possible solutions. Which of them would probably be to add `using YourProject.UrFolder`

Answer (score 0):

I ssume you copied this from some quite old source.

There **was** a `UnityStandardAssets.Characters.ThirdPerson.ThirdPersonUserControl` as the name suggests in the [StandardAssets](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/essentials/asset-packs/standard-assets-for-unity-2018-4-32351).

The last supported Unity version is `2018.4` though since afaik the concept of the "Standard" assets was given up by then.

So if you are still happen to use that version then just import the [StandardAssets](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/essentials/asset-packs/standard-assets-for-unity-2018-4-32351) via the Asset Store and in your script add

```
using UnityStandardAssets.Characters.ThirdPerson;
```

in newer Unity versions you might want to rather give it a shot with [Starter Assets - Third Person Character Controller](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/essentials/starter-assets-third-person-character-controller-196526#content) instead.